# Limit files uploaded per folder

Tags: images, media-library, uploads

I upload over thousands of images everyday and I want to limit the number of files that can be stored in a folder cause it's not good to have like 5000 files in a folder because it increases the load time. I want to do like this; for every 500 files uploaded auto create a new folder and upload it to that new folder. Is there a plugin/script that can do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And keep in mind: Plugin recommendations are off topic on this site. Use the G+ communities for such stuff.

Comment: I've tried Custom Upload Dir but it can't do what I want. If plugins are not allowed then I'm ok with script modifications. It's just that I'm not coder